# $f(x;\theta)=\dfrac{1}{\theta}e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}}$ , $x>0$ Type $1$ error ,Rejection region is $\overline{X} >6.296.$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

> Let $X_1,X_2,X_3 $ denote a random sample of size $3$ from population
> $X$ with probability density function.
>
> $f(x;\theta)=\dfrac{1}{\theta}e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}}$ , $x>0$
>
> The null hypothesis $H_0:\theta=3$ is to be rejected in favor of the
> alternative $H_\alpha:\theta\ne3$ if and only if $\overline{X}
>  >6.296.$ What is the significance level of the test?

I tried to do it as follows:

$1.\ \ \ X\sim exp(\alpha) , Y=\sum_{i}X_i \sim G(\alpha,n) $

Using gamma PDF $f_y(y)=\dfrac{a^{\lambda}e^{-ax}x^{n-1}}{\Gamma{n}}$

$\overline{X}\sim(na,n)$

$P(\overline{X}>6.296)=\int_{6.296}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-x}x^{2}}{2}dx$

$2. \text{If} \ \  \overline{X}\sim(na,n) ,2\overline{X}a \sim \chi_{n}^2 $

$P(Reject H_0|\theta=3)=P( \overline{X} >6.296)=P( 2\overline{X}\cdot\frac{1}{3} >6.296)$

Using both methods I get $\alpha=0.01$ but the answer given is $0.05$ I don't know what am I doing wrong please correct me and is there any other quick method to solve this problem?

Please try to use the same notations as me because I have an exam coming I don't want to get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience, let $c = 6.296$.  Then $$\begin{align}\Pr[\bar X > c] &= \int_{x=c}^\infty \frac{1}{2} x^2 e^{-x} \, dx \\
&= \left[ -\frac{1}{2} x^2 e^{-x} \right]_{x=c}^\infty + \int_{x=c}^\infty x e^{-x} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} c^2 e^{-c} + \left[ -x e^{-x} \right]_{x=c}^\infty + \int_{x=c}^\infty e^{-x} \, dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} c^2 e^{-c} + c e^{-c} + e^{-c} \\
&\approx 0.0499925.
 \end{align}$$

I do not know how you got $0.01$.  It is worth noting (this is not a coincidence) that if $X \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n, \theta)$, then $$\Pr[X > \lambda \theta] = \Pr[Y < n],$$ where $Y \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$.  Note that the gamma parametrization is by shape and scale.

Comment: Can you please look at my recent question regarding MLE of $\frac{1}{\theta}$ uniform distribution